# Javascript Regex replace the 6th occurrence of ; (semicolon) with ;\n (semicolon and newline)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
string = "bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;bla;";
```

bla is wildcard.

I want to update my string by inserting a newline (\n) at every 6th occurrence of a semicolon (;)

I have been trying to do this with regex:

---

```
var myregexvar = textbox.value;

myregexvar = myregexvar.replace(/\u003b.*\u003b.*\u003b.*\u003b\b/, /$1\n/);
```

---

/u003b is the unicode character code for ';'

it doesnt work. help!

Comment: You may want to look at [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17852821/483113).

Answer (score 2):

Try matching `(([^;]*;){5}[^;]*);` and replacing with `$1\n`.

The first grouped expression `([^;]*;){5}` looks for five `bla;`.  Then `[^;]*` takes the sixth `bla` (without the ;).  All of that gets grouped into `$1`.  Then the last semicolon is matched separately, so that it is left out and replaced with the `\n` from the replacing expression.

**Edit**

Didn't realize you wanted to **add** `\n` after every sixth semicolon, not replace.  You can use this simpler match expression: `([^;]*;){6}`.

Comment: THANKS! you relieved me of my hours of grief!
finished code:
myregexvar = myregexvar.replace(/(([^;]*;){5}[^;]*);/g, '$1\u003b\n');

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this **algorithm** may help u

```
$occurance = 6;
$count = 0;
while (/\u003b/gi) {
    if (++$count == $occurance) {
        myregexvar.replace(/\u003b/, /\n/);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really have the separate the `=  =` so much ?

Comment: I didnt try it because mellamokb's post was first and worked but thanks non the less!

Comment: This solution is more generic since it doesn't assume the same repetitive pattern. E.g., what if I wanted to replace the third 'blah' in the string 'blah and some blah blah blah text before more blah blah'? I found it useful, thanks.