# Replace or remove nth occurrence of \n

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my string:

```
var ok = "\n\n33333333333\n\n\n";
```

How to replace the 4th occurence of '\n' with ''?
Or, how to remove the 4th occurence of '\n'?

Comment: You just asked this, albeit in a different manner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121225/replacing-values-doesnt-work-ok-when-array-field-is-empty

Comment: Try ok.replace(/\n{4}/g, '')

Comment: @TamilSelvan that's not what that syntax does...

Comment: i've posted a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121225/replacing-values-doesnt-work-ok-when-array-field-is-empty/16121956

Answer (score 1):

- find n-1 occurences and other characters.
- capture the submatch.
- find the next occurence.
- replace the entire match with the captured submatch, and the
  replacement character/string

  `"AA33333333333AAA".replace(/((?:[^A]*A){3}[^A]*)A/,"$1k")`

(with `A` and `k` insteead of `\n` and `""` so you can more clearly see the results)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what, at least to me, is a fine readable solution:

```
var i = 0;
ok = ok.replace(/\n/g, function () {
  return ++i == 4 ? "" : "\n";
});
```

However, it might not win as far as performance is concerned.